# ¿Cual es la forma mas optima de recuperar una imagen desde la base de datos?

Tags: php, jquery, imagen, base64

Cuando almaceno las imagenes en la base de datos, se genera un blob demasiado grande que, cuando lo extraigo por medio de jquery tarda demasiado, y si son muchas imagenes es peor ya que la cadena de caracteres llena varias pantallas, suelo usar las imagenes base 64, pero como explico, no es optimo, existe alguna forma de almacenar sin tanto peso?

Comment: Tú lo has dicho. No es óptimo guardar imágenes en base de datos. Lo óptimo es guardar solo el nombre de la imagen, la cual cuando la sube el usuario lo único que haces es copiarla en tu servidor, digamos en la carpeta 'upimg'. Entonces cuando vayas a mostrar dichas imágenes o trabajar con ellas solo haces un select a tu tabla para que te devuelva el nombre de la imagen y se la concatenas a la ruta: 'la/ruta/estandar/'.$nombreImg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lo mas sencillo es guardar la imagen en un directorio específco por ejemplo "ruta/al/folder/especifico/" y guardar el nombre del archivo en la tabla en una columna tipo varchar.

Cuando quieras mostrarla en el sitio, solo requieres del nombre y escribes manualmente la ruta, por ejemplo

```
echo "<img src='ruta/al/folder/especifico/". $imagen ."'>"
```

Donde en la variable `$imagen` almacenas el nombre del archivo cuando consultaste la base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Tal como se indico la respuesta arriba, una solución rápida es guardar la ruta en la base de datos, junto con su nombre. La otra, es guardar la misma imagen en la base de datos, y esta puede ser guardada con un tipo de archivo BLOB, que te da un máximo de 4bg aproximadamente para guardarlo en un campo. Estos están tanto en bases de datos Oracle, MySQL, y SQL Server Aunque como solución práctica, te recomiendo la solución de Saul.